# Proto files using google.protobuf imports - causing issues in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have google.profobuf.* imports in a proto file (used by GRPC server written in go). When the same proto file is used to implement a GRPC client in NodeJS - I run into issues.

Details:

proto file used by the GRPC server (written in go):

tech.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package api;

import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

message Info {
    string desc = 1;
    google.protobuf.Duration ttl = 2;
}

service Tech {
    rpc BasicInfo(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Info) {}
}
```

When this is used by the GRPC client written in NodeJs:

getTechInfo.js (first few lines)

```
'use strict';

const PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/../../api/tech.proto';
const grpc = require('grpc');
const apiProto = grpc.load(PROTO_PATH).api;
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/././node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:4720
                            throw Error("failed to import '"+importFilename+"' in '"+filename+"': file not found");
                            ^

Error: failed to import '/Users/././api/google/protobuf/duration.proto' in '/Users/././api/register.proto': file not found
    at Builder.ProtoBuf.Builder.BuilderPrototype.import (/Users/././node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:4720:35)
    at Object.ProtoBuf.loadJson (/Users/././node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:5225:26)
    at Object.ProtoBuf.loadProto (/Users/././node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:5128:25)
    at Object.ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile (/Users/././node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:5174:52)
    at Object.load (/Users/././node_modules/grpc/index.js:135:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/././src/api/getTechInfo.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

The issue is with the imports in the proto file:

```
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
```

What is the recommended method to resolve these imports? Thanks in advance.

Using:

```
Node v8.9.4
"google-protobuf": "^3.5.0",
"grpc": "^1.10.1",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with the gRPC library, documented primarily in [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8339). The `grpc.load` API does not support easily loading `google/protobuf/*.proto` files.

The simplest solution is to use the `@grpc/proto-loader` library, which automatically includes `google/protobuf/*.proto` files when loading proto files.

One alternative solution is to use `grpc-tools` to pre-generate files that can be used with the `google-protobuf` library.